# IIS globalization and Spanish (Latin America) es-419

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

IIS does not handle the "es-419" correctly.  Is there a workaround to get it to work?  I am using the following to get the Thread local uiculture set.

```
<globalization  uiCulture="auto" culture="auto"/>
```

That works fine for all the locales i have tried except for "es-419" which is common from Chrome browsers.  If "es-419" is in the list it just uses the default local instead of es.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this helps you out to create a custom culture, since the numbered cultures aren't supported.

- [How to: Create Custom Cultures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)